# Calculus word problem dealing with rectangle

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

How would I figure this problem out.

A rectangle has a base B and a height H. Assuming that is area remains constant express the rate of change of the height with respect to the base.

this is what I did.

I know that $area=bh$

so therefore $h=\frac{a}{b}$

taking the derivative $\frac{dh}{db}$ I got $A-1(b)^{-2}$

but would this be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is constant, recall, so we treat it as such:

$$h=\frac{A}{b}\implies \frac{dh}{db}=\frac{d}{db}\left(\frac{A}{b}\right)=A\frac{d}{db}\left( b^{-1} \right)=A\cdot\left( -1\cdot b^{-2}\right)\;=\;-\frac{A}{b^2}$$

where $a = A = $ area, $b = $ base.

Perhaps that what you meant: that $A$ multiplies $-1b^{-2}$, like $A\cdot(-1\cdot b^{-2}) = -\dfrac{A}{b^2},\;$ with $A$ being area, $b$ the base. In that case your answer was correct, but should take care to use parentheses and dots to denote multiplication (otherwise it looks like you are subtracting $-1b^{-2}$ from $A$).

Comment: Does this make sense, Fernando?

Comment: indeed it does.

Answer (score 2):

If $h=\frac Ab$, then $\frac{dh}{db}=-\frac{A}{b^2}$, since $A$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

If $h=\frac{a}{b}$ then $\frac{dh}{db}=\frac{d}{db}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=a\frac{d}{db}\left( b^{-1} \right)=a\cdot\left( -1\cdot b^{-2}\right)=-\frac{a}{b^2}$.

(Use formula $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$)